# create a dynamic query to print ranges and sum of an integer column corresponding to each range

Tags: sql, oracle

ex:

There is a table which contains data as follows
The data gets added dynamically.
The range difference has to be 100.
Each range should display the sum of the rate(MRP) column of all transactions in that range.

```
TransactionID   MRP
1               100
2               201
3               301
4               401
5               501
7               100
8               201
9               301
10              401
11              501


Price Range     Sum of MRP
100 - 200       200
201 - 300       402
301 - 400       602
401 - 500       802
501 - 600       1002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create ranges using `UNION ALL` and then you can JOIN with your table

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(t1.start,'-',t1.end) AS `Price Range`,
SUM(t.MRP) as `Sum of MRP`
FROM
test t
JOIN
(SELECT 100 as start,200 as end
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 200 as start,300 as end 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 300 as start,400 as end
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 400 as start,500 as end
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT 500 as start,600 as end) as t1
ON t.MRP>=t1.start and t.MRP<=t1.end
GROUP BY t1.start,t1.end
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/95EqCHA8meihpNYKhcVAAp/1)

**UPDATE**

*NOTE: I am using **Mysql*** ,I try to compile in oracle

If you want Dynamics then you can use this

```
set @start = 200;
set @end = 100;

SELECT 
CONCAT(t1.start,'-',t1.end) AS `Price Range`,
SUM(t.MRP) as `Sum of MRP`
FROM
test t
JOIN
( SELECT 100 as start,200 as end
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT (@start := @end+1) as start,(@end := @start+99) as end FROM test) as t1
ON t.MRP>=t1.start and t.MRP<=t1.end
GROUP BY t1.start,t1.end
```

[DEMO FOR DYNAMIC](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/95EqCHA8meihpNYKhcVAAp/2)

Comment: Thank you. What if tommorow another transaction came with MRP as 700. our requirement is to create another range dynamically

Comment: Second query is what I need and is working in mysql.

Comment: @TomG - if you wanted a MySQL solution why did you tag this question `[oracle]`?